# Reassociate files types for visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file, associations

I've had an install of 2012 for a while, but I've had to also just install VS 2010. As expected, all my file associations now point to VS2010 and the icons aren't so intuitive. Without doing each file manually through the explorer menu, how can I quickly revert/change the associations back to VS2012?

Comment: I can't try now, but can you: Open Visual Studio > Go to Tools > Options. When the Options dialog opens, looks at the lower left corner for a ‘Show all Settings’ checkbox.
Select this checkbox > Go to General Page of Environment and click the ‘Restore File Associations’ button.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Open VisualStudio  -  `Tools > Options`.

Then go to General Page of Environment and click the `Manage File Associations` button.

A Window in the controlpanel will be opened(Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Default Programs\Set Program Associations)

.Select Extensions you want to associate to VisualStudio2012 and click the `Save` button.

Comment: Seriously.... scroll through a list of thousands of file types trying to find the needles-in-a-haystack types that may be opened by Visual Studio and then click each and every one trying to find the Visual Studio 2015 exe?  Insane.  Not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer only assignes file extensions to Visual Studio as a whole. To tell VS how to handle a file extension (like syntax highlighting), go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension and add your extension to the list.