# Set Visual Studio 2010 as default after installing VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio 2012  after I had already VS 2010.
All project files where changed to be opened with VS 2012.
When I try to change the default program (right click - open with ) I don't get VS 2010 as an optional program.
When I try to choose the devenv.exe file from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE as default program it still open VS 2012.
How can I set VS 2010 as my default IDE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reassociate files types for visual studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996907/reassociate-files-types-for-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: Run File Associations button doesn't help. I still have the same behavior

Comment: Check the .sln files you are opening... if they have "Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00" then the multi-selector that handles the launch is correctly opening them with VS 2012 rather than VS 2010.