# xaml.cs files are opened in Notepad

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Due to some power failure my system got shutdown and now when I am opening the project all the abc.xaml.cs files are getting opened in notepad

I have tried to find auto recovery backup at **Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Backup Files\project** but here is nothing.

Please help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: I've removed the screenshot of Notepad because I wasn't sure it added anything to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the association between the file type and Visual Studio has been lost. Try the steps @ [Reassociate files types for visual studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996907/reassociate-files-types-for-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: no i don't think so because other files for the same file type are working fine.Problem is in one file only.